# Permissions of .git for repository with multiple users

Tags: git, permissions

I have a git repository on a network directory. I need to set the permissions on the `.git` directory such that everyone on my team (they are all part of the same UNIX group) can modify the repository, e.g., push, pull, commit, etc.

I'm reluctant to do something like

```
chmod -R g+rwX .git
```

because I'm not sure if that will mess up the permissions and make it so that the repository will become corrupted.

What should the permissions be in the `.git` directory? How can I keep them that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want g+rwX.  You also want to set core.sharedRepository = group.